# AD-HOC SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Dynamic creation and deletion of an SQL Agent Job

I have created a stored procedure that creates a number of dynamic agent jobs. The stored procedure creates/runs then deletes an Agent Job perfectly. This does mean that there could be a number of jobs running at once.

This allows me to spawn a number of parallel running jobs, shifting data around rather than doing it sequentially.

At each stage success or failure is logged to a table so at a glance I can see what has failed or completed.

Is the use of spawning multiple Agent jobs from a stored procedure like this practical?

It works well and cuts my load time considerably.

Comment: Why would you recreate the agent job every single time? You can start jobs at the same time (though it's not usually a good idea). What is *load time* here? What's the end goal? It sounds like an XY Problem.